# Transparent PDF background using FPDF

Tags: php

using FPDF to generate PDFs that are being printed. (Part of [THIS](http://dizzi.ladela.com/) plugin)

The background of the generated PDFs is always coming white, I need it to be transparent to enable printing onto items with background colour other than white.

**Can this be done using FPDF?**

Below is the code used to generate the PDF.

```
public function executeExportPdf()
{
    $content_images = $this->getParameter("content_images");
    if (!is_array($content_images) || !count($content_images)) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
        exit();
    }

    $height = intval($this->getParameter('height'));
    $width  = intval($this->getParameter('width'));
    $dpi    = intval($this->getParameter('dpi'));

    if (!$height || !$width || !$dpi) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'The pdf options is not valid'));
        exit();
    }

    $orientation = $height > $width ? 'P' : 'L';
    $PDF = new FPDF($orientation, 'mm', array($height, $width));

    $color_scheme = $this->getParameter('color_scheme') == '1' ? 'cmyk' : 'rgb';

    foreach ($content_images as $content_image) {

        if ($color_scheme == 'cmyk') {
            if (class_exists("Imagick")) {

                $content_image = substr($content_image, 23); // remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," - text
                $imagick = new Imagick();
                $imagick->readImageBlob(base64_decode($content_image));
                $imagick->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
                $content_image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($imagick->getImageBlob());
            }
        }

        $PDF->AddPage();
        $PDF->Image($content_image, 0, 0, -$dpi , -$dpi, 'JPG');
    }

    $PDF->Output("order-{$this->getParameter('order', 0)}.pdf", 'D');
    die();
}
```